# Java Could not find agent library hprof on the library path

Tags: java, performance, profile, hprof

I was trying to profile CPU usage in my code and discovered the built-in hprof. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html

However, as I tested I got the following error:

`javac -J-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples Main.java`
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library hprof on the library path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries

I believe I am having a path issue, however, I have no clue of where this library is located to try adding to the path, I am using the `jdk-15.0.2.`

- I have already tried to look for "hprof" in my jdk folder, however can´t find anything.
- So I tried to check in the documentation, however, I could only find a path for a demo for the javase8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr008.html#BABIDBJJ. However, it points to a demo code JAVA_HOME/demo/jvmti/hprof that does not exist in my jdk.

Does anyone have an idea of what could I try to find the exact location?
Or any other alternative/Visual Studio Code extension to profile a java code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: hprof [has been removed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046661) in JDK 9, and is not supposed to work in later JDK versions. You may use [JDK Mission Control](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk-mission-control.html) instead, or many of third party Java profilers, e.g. a lightweight yet powerful [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/).

Comment: That explains a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like HPROF was removed in JDK 9. Here's some alternatives: https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/12/OpenJDK-9-removal-of-HPROF-jhat/